# How does C see "|" in if statement?

Tags: c

hi i wanted to ask if in this part of my program it will check if array element is either #,S or D because it doesnt seems to work

```
    if(cis[0][1]!='#'|'D'|'S'){printf("something");
```

Comment: What you need is || not |

Comment: @ThePlatypus That's the smallest of his problems :-)

Comment: true: look at haccks response. I believe that's the correct way of doing it

Comment: about 5 minutes ago there was such silly question as that and it got -10, and no answer. why there are 5 answers?

Comment: If I don't make any mistake in my bitwise calculation, your line is strictly equivalent to `if(cis!='w'){print("something");` :)

Comment: @Bentoy13: The characters are not combined with `|`, because `!=` has higher precedence. And, if it did not, the C standard does not guarantee that C implementations use ASCII.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right! Since bitwise operators have a higher precedence than logical ones, I extend this logically to comparison operators :(. So the OP is reduced to `if('W'){print("something");`, if ASCII is used, as stated by dasblinkenlight in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way of checking a character against a group of characters is [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) function:

```
if (!strchr("#DS", cis[0][1])) {
    printf("something");
}
```

Let us now consider your original expression. Yo wrote this:

```
cis[0][1]!='#'|'D'|'S'
```

In C, the `|` operator represents bitwise "OR" operation. It has lower precedence than `!=`, so the expression will evaluate to 87:

- `'D'` is `68`<sub>10</sub>, or `01000100`<sub>2</sub>
- `'S'` is `83`<sub>10</sub>, or `01010011`<sub>2</sub>

"OR"ing them together produces `01010111`<sub>2</sub>, or `57`<sub>10</sub>, which is interpreted as `true` by the `if` statement, because it is not zero.

Therefore, your code fragment is equivalent to this:

```
if (57) {
    printf("something");
}
```

which is definitely not what you intended.

A more common way of combining conditions is with the short-circuiting `||` for "OR" and `&&` for "AND". You need to include complete conditions, for example

```
A == B || A == C
```

you cannot replace this with

```
A == B || C // <<== Incorrect!
```

This would compile, but it would mean a different thing.

Answer (score 5):

It will not. `|` a bit wise OR operator. You need logical OR `||` operator.

```
if(cis[0][1]=='#' || cis[0][1]== 'D' || cis[0][1] == 'S'){printf("something");
```

Note that, using

```
if(cis[0][1] !='#' || cis[0][1] != 'D' || cis[0][1] != 'S') { ... }
```

will make your condition `cis[0][1] !='#' || cis[0][1] != 'D' || cis[0][1] != 'S'` always true. But to achieve your requirement use `&&` as

```
if(cis[0][1] !='#' && cis[0][1] != 'D' && cis[0][1] != 'S') { ... }
```

Comment: There's a third mistake, this condition is always true.

Comment: `switch` may look cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise OR operator doesn't work that way. You need:

```
if (cis[0][1] != '#' && cis[0][1] != 'D' && cis[0][1] != 'S') { printf("something"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `switch` and `case`:

```
switch(cis[0][1]) {
    case '#':
    case 'D':
    case 'S':
       break;
    default:
       printf("something");
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a `break` instruction in the `default` case. Behavior will be unchanged, but it will prevent your code from behaving oddly if you were to add `case`s after the `default` in the future (why not?).

Comment: @Diti if you add break to default and then add case after the default, this case will be never executed

Comment: Do you have an example of such a behavior? I just tested it with https://gist.github.com/Diti/7684035 and it demonstrates my previous comment's point.

Comment: @Diti you are right it was missunderstand of the switch case from me. Thank you for the info